# if $ \int f(x) $ converges and the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(f(x))$ exists then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(f(x)) = 0$?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be bounded.

if $ \int f(x) $ from 1 to infinity converges and the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(f(x))$ exists then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(f(x)) = 0$ ?

I can't think of a counter example to disprove this. is it correct?

Comment: Your notation is not clear, what kind of integral is this, on which interval do we integrate? What do we know about $f$?

Comment: If we have that the limit exists, then assume it isn't zero and see what happens to the integral.

Comment: @rae306 i'm sorry my Latex is quite poor, this integral goes from 1 to infinity. other than that i've given you all the info i was given.

Comment: You may proceed like this: $S_n=\int_{0}^{n} f(x) dx$. And $S_n=\sum a_n , a_n=f(1+nh)h$ as for large $N$ $n>N$ $|S_{n+1}-S_n|<\epsilon$ that means $|S_{n+1}-S_n|=|a_{n+1}| < \epsilon$ for any $n>N$. .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the limit existed and didn't equal $0$. WLOG it equals $L>0$. This means there is some $M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for $x\geq M$, $f(x)>L/2>0$. Then $\int _M^{\infty} f(x)\,dx > \int _{M}^{\infty} L/2\,dx$, which diverges. Similarly if $L<0$. Then we must have $L=0$.

Comment: why does $ \int _{M}^{\infty} f(M)+(L/2)(x-M)\,dx $ diverge ?

Comment: Whoops, typo.

It's interesting to note that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ is not a necessary condition for $\int _0^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ to exist. Some examples include $f(x) = \sin(x)\sin(x^2)$, and $f_n(x) = 1/n$ if $|x-n|<n^{-3}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$.